# Zoom like in d3heatmap

Tags: r, echarts4r, d3heatmap

Is there a way to zoom heatmaps in echarts4r similar to d3heatmap? (https://github.com/rstudio/d3heatmap).  The purpose is to use the callbacks in echarts4r to trigger events when clicking and hovering over on the heatmap which d3heatmap doesn't have (that I know of).

This code is copied from (https://echarts4r.john-coene.com/articles/chart_types.html#heatmap) with the addition of the brush.  The brush shows and can select a zoom window, however the chart doesn't zoom.

```
v <- LETTERS[1:10]
matrix <- data.frame(
  x = sample(v, 300, replace = TRUE), 
  y = sample(v, 300, replace = TRUE), 
  z = rnorm(300, 10, 1),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
) %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(x, y) %>% 
  dplyr::summarise(z = sum(z)) %>% 
  dplyr::ungroup()

matrix %>% 
  e_charts(x) %>% 
  e_heatmap(y, z) %>% 
  e_visual_map(z) %>% 
  e_title("Heatmap") %>%
  e_brush() # add the brush
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The brush and the zoom are two different things in echarts: use `e_datazoom` instead.

```
v <- LETTERS[1:10]
matrix <- data.frame(
  x = sample(v, 300, replace = TRUE), 
  y = sample(v, 300, replace = TRUE), 
  z = rnorm(300, 10, 1),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
) %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(x, y) %>% 
  dplyr::summarise(z = sum(z)) %>% 
  dplyr::ungroup()

matrix %>% 
  e_charts(x) %>% 
  e_heatmap(y, z) %>% 
  e_visual_map(z) %>% 
  e_title("Heatmap") %>%
  e_datazoom() # use zoom
```